# What to do when we can't apply the implicit function theorem?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, implicit-function-theorem

Consider $f(x,y,z)=xy\exp^{xz}-z\ln{y}=0$. It is clear by the implicit function theorem that we can solve for $x=x(y,z)$ around $(0,1,0)$. But as

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,1,0)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(0,1,0)=0$$

we cannot do the same for $y=y(x,z)$ and $z=(x,y)$. How can I verify if these cases are or not possible (since the theorem doens't imply impossibility for them)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great question. Here's a hint for one solution: What's the second degree Taylor polynomial for $f$ at the point in question? Using it, can you locally solve for either $y$ or $z$?

Comment: Following your tip, I'd get $f(x,y,z)\approx xy$. I may have misunderstood your point, but how can I use a Taylor approximation to formally argue the existence or non-existence of local solutions $y=y(x,z)$ and $z=z(x,y)$?

Comment: Don't you get $f(x,y,z)\approx x + (y-1)(x-z) + \dots$? Set this equal to $0$ and can you solve for $y$ or $z$ near $(0,1,0)$? If you could solve for $y$ or $z$ as a differentiable function, you'd have to get the same answer from this (up to whatever order) ...

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not familiar with multivariable higher-than-one-order Taylor approximation and made some mistakes. Now I'm getting $f(x,y,z)\approx x+(x-z)(y-1)$, as you said, which can be solved for $y=z/(x-z)$ (if $x\neq z$) and $z=xy/y-1$ (if $y\neq 1$), both non-differentiable at (0,1,0). So with this we can conclude that our original $f$ can't be solved for $y=y(x,z)$ or $z=z(x,y)$ since the second-order approximation can't. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, it's easiest just to use the usual single-variable Taylor polynomials for $e^u$ and $\ln(1+u)$ and then substitute ... You can convince yourself why this is valid. :)